# Methods for tracking and showing progress for Firestore reads and writes in an Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, user-experience

I have Firestore Triggered Firebase Cloud Functions validating updates to Firestore documents, that is an async process that can take time especially when instance is warming up (20seconds+). The nature of this architecture means that the client does not see changes it makes to a Firestore document until the validation completes, thus it is not even possible to say add a flag field to indicate that the document is undergoing validation (a hint to show progress). If I were doing this using sqlite then a local field could be used to track in the local DB while kept separate from the uploaded data, Firestore does not cater to such AFAIK.

I wonder if there is anything out-of-the-box that facilitates tracking such activities in Firestore or neat ideas to solve this?

In the meantime I track such activities with a side-band, locally stored data mechanism and it feels archaic.